# Getting text from previous activity and adding it another activities list view

Tags: java, android, listview

How do I add items to a list dynamically when button is clicked? The text is added to the `listView`. At the moment it only adds one item to the list view, and when you try to add another it just changes the already added item in the list.

Here is my code:

This is the button on click for activity A that gets the text:

```
schedule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View view) {

             AddSchedule();

             Intent i = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
             String str = event_name.getText().toString();
             i.putExtra("myExtra", str);
             startActivity(i);

         }

     });
```

Then in activity B it gets the text from activity B but only adds the

Final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("myExtra")) {
        list.add(i.getStringExtra("myExtra"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: post your complete code please

Comment: I have  just edited the code to show what is happening in activity A and B. If that helps

Answer (score 1):

You only see one item in the new activty's list, since that Activity is created each time via startActivity(Intent) (I suppose). So each time open Activity B, it's a new instance. The arraylist is empty.

You need to keep track of the items clicked in Activity A and send the whole list to Activity B, every time. Activity B should get the complete list in the intent and create the gui-list.

Make your class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or `Serializable` (slower).

Comment: not sure I quiet understand, so every time the button is click it needs to be parcelable to other activities

Answer (score 0):

Inside activity B you should include the following:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
    out.putStringArrayList(key, list);
}
```

"key" is a final String you have defined in Activity's B member variables.

This will make sure your list is saved before being destroyed (For more, read about [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). Now, you also need to restore in whenever the activity is created. You can do that in `onCreateView` like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //restore the contents of your list
    if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(key);

    /* initialize the adapter and set it to the list */

    //also add the new item from activity A
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("myExtra")) {
        list.add(i.getStringExtra("myExtra"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

General note, instead of adding to the list and afterwards notifying the adapter, you can instead add your items directly to the adapter. The adapter will automatically update your list.

Edit: Yes, your list should be a member variable because it needs to be accessed in 2 methods.

Comment: what about the list?  is that also a variable?

Comment: @user3461038 list should be a member variable because it needs to be accessed in 2 methods. Don't forget to initialize it!